# How Self Sovereign Identity works in Blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, consensus, identity

Today i have read about Self Sovereign Identity. It has 10 principle to hold the individuals identity. Really it is such a nice concept. When in near future it is fully implemented it will solve lots of problems.

But as a newbie my question is how it works? For example i want to store my driving licence with the help of Self Sovereign Identity in Blockchain. So that later i can use the hash function of my driving licence (as in Blockchain every data is stored as hash function) whenever i need it. But my question is, how can the minors come to know my driving licence is valid one and i didnot staor fake licence.

I think my question is related to Self Sovereign Identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately nobody supply me the document. I guess it serve my purpose. If you are working on the same thing probably help you also.

https://github.com/WebOfTrustInfo/ID2020DesignWorkshop/blob/master/topics-and-advance-readings/a-self-sovereign-identity-architecture.pdf

[image]